# Clustered Column with same row values

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I can't seem to get a good clustered column when the row values are the same. How do I create a chart that has the same row value title but a different x axis title? For example, in the image below I want the sections RM clustered together and CEN to be another cluster.
[image]

Comment: tried to insert and empty column in between Rm and CEN data ?

Comment: RM and CEN should be plotted as separate series. Select your chart, change the source and add two new series, then delete the one you have already

Answer (score 0):

Clustered column charts are designed to cluster the values for each series (e.g., RM and CEN) for a given category on the X axis (e.g., "a" in my first chart below). But your data isn't arranged into nice pairs like that. And you don't really want a clustered chart like that.

Your data is all in just two columns, one with the repeated labels, and one with values. What complicates it is the unequal number of values for each label. One of the comments under your original question was on the right track, to insert space between them. In the second data range in my screen shot, I've inserted a blank row between RM and CEN, and the resulting chart clumps all RM values on one side and all CEN on the other, with the blank row providing space in the chart. This could be a clustered or stacked chart, doesn't matter, since there's only one series.

Let's do it one better. Move the CEN into the next column, and put the RM and CEN labels above the two data columns. I've pout dummy category labels in the first column ("a" through "k"). I made a column chart, and the two clumps look much the way I think you want the to look. You can make a clustered column chart, but then you'll have to format either one of the series and change overlap to 100%. Or you could make a stacked column chart, and format either series and make gap width smaller.

[image: Clumped Column Chart]